# Update app from the application

Tags: c#, auto-update

I am trying to develop a feature in my app, which will enable users to check for the updates and, if new version exists (on the FTP server), it will download all the new files and run the new instance of the application.

I have successfully managed to check for an update (by comparing XML files) and downloading the zip file from the FTP server into a temporary folder. However once I started copying the files into the main folder, application suddenly crashed becuase all the dll's I have tried to copy were already in use.

I came with two approaches that are possible:

1) rename all the files under the main folder to: originalname.dll.bak (append .bak to the end of their name). Then copy original files and restart application. Upon opening new instance (updated exe file), the very first thing we do is that we erase old files ending with .bak. One problem with this approach is, that I can easily rename currently running process to include .bak, yet I am not sure if I can do the same with the dll files (have not implemented this solution yet)

2) Create an external app (e.g. console app), which will be executed from the main application whcih will handle the update process. Upon opening this external updater, my main app will immediately close so that we can assure that copying of the new files will be without a problem.

I have not done any of this before therefore any comments & suggestions will be more than welcome. Also shall shall there be any better way how to handle the update process, I would be more than happy to implement it.

Comment: is `click-once` an option?

Comment: I would prefer the second option since the first one looks like a murky business. If I ain't wrong that is why you have seperate exe for install/uninstall and running the app.And that is why you need to keep the app closed

Comment: I've done a project like this with the second way you've offered and after two years, still think this would be the better solution to handle the situation

Comment: I have used install shield le to deploy my app, therefore click once would not be an option. I will probably go with the second option, just wanted to check if there is a better way